# Which type of association?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to store teams and their matches in a database. There are several teams and several matches. Every match is played by two teams.

This is my MySQL scheme.

```
CREATE TABLE teams (
   id INT(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
   name VARCHAR(255) NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (id),
   UNIQUE KEY (name)
);

CREATE TABLE matches (
   id INT(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
   datetime datetime NULL,
   team_home INT(11) NOT NULL,
   team_guest INT(11) NOT NULL,
   result_home INT(11) NOT NULL,
   guest_home INT(11) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (id),
   FOREIGN KEY (team_home) REFERENCES teams (id),
   FOREIGN KEY (team_guest) REFERENCES teams (id)
);
```

Now I'd like to build these schemes in Rails, but I have no idea to choose the right associations. How can I do references over two fields (in my example team_home and team_guest to teams)?

Comment: Rails is having it's own capability read http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html#schema-dumping-and-you to understand more..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @Sumit Munot said you should go through the guides, lots of good information there

as a learning exercise try using some of rails generators to see how rails likes things named

```
rails generate model Team name:string 
rails generate model Match start_at:datetime team_home_id:integer team_away_id:integer score_home_team:integer score_away_team:integer
```

then view and modify the files created in `db/migrations` adding `null: false` as needed

NOTE: I changed some of your column names slightly

once your migrations are dialed create your database tables using `rake db:migrate`

then modify the models that were generated in `app/models` and add the relationships

```
class Team
  has_many :home_matches, class_name: "Match", foreign_key: "team_home_id"
  has_many :away_matches, class_name: "Match", foreign_key: "team_away_id"

  def matches
    (home_matches + away_matches).flatten.sort_by(:start_at)
  end
end

class Match
  belongs_to :home_team, class_name: "Match", foreign_key: "team_home_id"
  belongs_to :away_team, class_name: "Match", foreign_key: "team_away_id"
end
```

Normal associations do not need to be so complex, lets say you had a Player model i.e.

```
rails generate model Player name:string team_id:integer

class Player
  belongs_to :team
end

class Team
  has_many :players
end
```

as long as the `players` table has a `team_id` column it will just 'work'

Comment: Thanks @house9! Does it mean that I have to add the foreign keys for team_home_id and team_away_id manually in my database? I tried to create a team in rails console using `Team.new(name: 'Teamname')`, then I got `ArgumentError: Unknown key: foreign_key_id`...

Comment: my bad - it should be `foreign_key`, not `foreign_key_id` - updating post now